# how to add xmlns attribute to an existing xml document

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have existing xml document.

e.g

```
<Test>
  <A />
</Test>
```

I load this xml into XDocument. I need to add attribute xmlns to this document and save it with this attribute.

```
var xml = new XDocument.Load("c:\\filePath.xml");
```

When I'm trying this:

```
xml.Root.SetAttributeValue("xmlns", "http://namespaceuri");
```

I'm getting exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The prefix '' cannot be redefined from 'http://namespaceuri' to  within the same start element tag.
```

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to change the namespace of the `Test` and `A` elements?

Comment: no, i just want to add xmlns attribute to the root element. the answer from Jon solved my problem.

Comment: The answer from Jon changed the namespace of the elements

Comment: yes it is correct. when i add xmlns to the xml, it is a default namespace, so all elements in the document will use this default namespace.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was asking. You want to change the namespace of the existing elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the names to be in the namespace as well:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://namespaceuri";
foreach (var element in xml.Descendants().ToList())
{
    element.Name = ns + element.Name.LocalName;
}
xml.Root.SetAttributeValue("xmlns", ns.ToString());
```

Basically you're trying to move all the elements to that namespace *and* make it the default namespace for the root element down. You can't change the default namespace while leaving the element itself in a different-but-unqualified namespace.

Using the code above with your sample XML (fixed to close `A`) ends up with:

```
<Test xmlns="http://namespaceuri">
  <A />
</Test>
```

Note that this code will change the namespace of *all* elements. If you want to be more selective, you should add a `Where` call after the `xml.Descendants()` call, e.g.

```
foreach (var element in xml.Descendants()
                           .Where(x => x.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None)
                           .ToList())
```